# Collectives icons are duplicated while inline tag editing

Tags: bug, status-review, collectives, inline-tag-editor

There is a duplicate icon displayed with the [inline tag editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege in the [Collectives questions](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives).

While editing the tags of the post using the "Edit tags" option, the Collectives icon is duplicated.

**GIF for reference:**

> [image: Duplicate icons]

Comment: I believe the intent was to show the current vs the new tag associations, but I agree it looks a bit odd.  I'll raise it with the team and see what we can do.

Comment: Still happens. Noticed this with the PHP collective tag